# Svelte: Variable not changing on input change?

Tags: javascript, svelte

Just trying to use variables like in react and vue where when the value changes it actually changes? Here my login data is always empty even after filling out the inputs...

```
<script>
    import axios from 'axios';

    let email = '';
    let password = '';

    function handleOnSubmit() {
        axios.post('http://localhost:5000/auth/token', {
            data: {
                Email: email,
                Password: password
            }
        })
        .then(function (response) {
        });
    }
</script>

<form on:submit={handleOnSubmit}>
                <div class="mb-6">
                    <label for="email" class="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" id="email" class="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500" value={email} placeholder="name@flowbite.com" required>
                </div>
                <div class="mb-6">
                    <label for="password" class="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" id="password" class="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500" value={password} required>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="text-white bg-blue-700 hover:bg-blue-800 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-300 font-medium rounded text-sm w-full sm:w-auto px-5 py-2.5 text-center dark:bg-blue-600 dark:hover:bg-blue-700 dark:focus:ring-blue-800">Sign In</button>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `bind:value={email}` instead of `value={email}`

I modified your code so that it works. Removed the style because it is annoying to look at.

```
<script>
  let email = "";
  let password = "";

  function handleOnSubmit() {
    console.log(email, password);
  }
</script>

<form on:submit|once|preventDefault="{handleOnSubmit}">
  <div class="mb-6">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input
      type="email"
      id="email"
      bind:value="{email}"
      placeholder="name@flowbite.com"
      required
    />
  </div>
  <div class="mb-6">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input id="password" type="password" bind:value="{password}" required />
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Click me</button>
</form>
```